# Texmaker on Ubuntu Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

My bibliography does not compile with my document.
i tried to adjust the configure settings but now it is having difficulty compiling (taking to long).

[image: options>configu>quickbuild]

[image: options>config>commands]

here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns} 

\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {./pictures and cover/} }

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}

  {0pt}{.5\baselineskip}{.3\baselineskip}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}

  {0pt}{15pt}{3pt}

  \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}

  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\cfoot{\thepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subfiles}



\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amssymb}



\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}



\pagestyle{myheadings}

\markright{The Economics of Religious Philosophy}




\usepackage{tocbibind}


\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{xpatch}



\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
What is most important is to leave the substance intact. \cite{gupta2005walking}

\printbibliography

\end{document}


@article{gupta2005walking,
  title={Walking a theological tightrope: Controversies of sampradaya in eighteenth century Caitanya Vaisnavism},
  author={Gupta, Ravi M},
  journal={ISKCON Communications Journal},
  volume={11},
  pages={39--51},
  year={2005}
}
```

Comment: I don't use texmaker but your commandline for **User**  looks wrong: you appear to be passing %.pdf ie the name of a pdf file, to pdflatex. That can not work.

Comment: Welcome. // Suggestion: remove duplicated packages and everything you really do not need by now ...

Comment: When you say that it takes too long do you mean that it takes so long that it does not finish at all or just that in practice you get slightly annoyed waiting for it to compile? You don't have to run the "LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX"-cycle after every single change in your document. You only need to run Biber if something that is relevant for citations or the bibliography changes (`biblatex` will tell you about some of these cases in the `.log` file - it won't warn you in case the `.bib` file has changed, you need to remember to run Biber in that case yourself).

Comment: If I were you I'd probably leave quick build at something like "pdfLaTeX + View PDF", configure the "Bib(la)tex" on the second screenshot to run `biber %` and then usually run the quick build and Biber (via the "Bib(la)tex" button/key binding) whenever required (and periodically just to make sure).